# auto-fill and auto-hscroll interferes, causing unnecessary horizontal scrolling

Tags: auto-fill-mode

When both `auto-fill-mode` and `auto-hscroll-mode` are enabled, I often end up with a window that is horizontally scrolled, even though the entire content of the window should fit into an unscrolled window.

For example:

```
Emacs -Q
M-x toggle-truncate-lines RET
M-x auto-fill-mode RET
C-u 60 x
SPC
C-u 60 y
SPC
```

After the `y`:s have been inserted, `auto-hscroll` correctly scrolls the window so that the point is visible.

However, after the final SPC, the `x`:s and `y`:s are on separate lines, each short enough to be visible. Yet, the window still is horizontally scrolled.

Is there any setting or package that would make the window return to it's unscrolled state, once there is no need for it to be scrolled?